# Read multilanguage strings from html via Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, url-encoding

I am new in python 2.7 and I am trying to extract some info from html files. More specifically, I wand to read some text information that contains multilanguage information. I give my script hopping to make things more clear.

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
dom = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page)
data = dom.findAll('meta', {'name' : 'keywords'})

print data[0]['content'].encode("utf-8")
```

the result I am taking is

```
BBCϊ╕φόΨΘύ╜ΣΎ╝Νϊ╕╗ώκ╡Ύ╝Νbbcchinese.com, email news, newsletter, subscription, full text
```

The problem is in the first string. Is there any way to print what exactly I am reading? Also is there any way to find the exact encoding of the language of each script?

**PS**: I would like to mention that the site selected totally randomly as it is representative to the problem I am encountering.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with the terminal where you are outputting the result. The script works fine and if you output data to file you will get it correctly.

**Example:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
dom = BeautifulSoup(page)
data = dom.findAll('meta', {'name' : 'keywords'})

with open("test.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(data[0]['content'].encode("utf-8"))
```

**test.txt:**

```
BBC中文网，主页，bbcchinese.com, email news, newsletter, subscription, full text
```

Which OS and terminal you are using?

Comment: I am using Win 7 64x and I am calling .py files via cmd.

Comment: CMD gives me the same result. Here are similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706097/how-to-do-proper-unicode-and-ansi-output-redirection-on-cmd-exe) or this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how).