# Show characters with accents in redirect file (>output.txt)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, console-output

example

```
mode con: cp>%tmp%\output.tmp
notepad %tmp%\output.tmp
```

show:

```
Statut du p‚riph‚rique CON:
---------------------------
    Page de codesÿ:   850
```

instead of:

```
Statut du périphérique CON:
---------------------------
    Page de codes :   850
```

I also tried with `chcp 65001` and `1252`

Do you know a fix?

Edit:

I use the truetype Lucida fonts, and even if I do `type %tmp%\output.tmp` it shows the right characters in console, but not in any text editor.

I also tried:

```
cmd /U /C "chcp 65001>nul &mode con: cp>%tmp%\output.tmp"
```

and

```
cmd /A /C "chcp 65001>nul &mode con: cp>%tmp%\output.tmp"
```

without success

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2708563/5047996)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the /U switch of `cmd.exe` in order to output Unicode characters. For example:

```
cmd /U /C dir > dirInUnicode.txt
```

However, this switch works on internal commands only, so you must use an auxiliary file in order to convert the output of `mode` command:

```
mode con: cp>%tmp%\output1.tmp
cmd /U /C type %tmp%\output1.tmp > %tmp%\output2.tmp
```

Comment: Example in non english console with: `netsh advfirewall show current state>%tmp%\tmp.tmp &cmd /U /C "type %tmp%\tmp.tmp>%tmp%\tmp2.tmp" &notepad %tmp%\tmp2.tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell instead of DOS as a command line prompt. Its works flawlessly with special characters.

```
C:> powershell
PS C:> mode con: cp > temp.txt
PS C:> notepad temp.txt
```